# XAMPP: Script wont stop execution when it is left (run it background until "done")

Tags: php, xampp

I'm currently working on a project. I'm making a chat.

My Goal is to use an `EventSource` which allows me to save resources. I've used them before on my host and everything worked fine with both the `JavaScript` and `PHP`.

I'm currently using the `XAMPP` server to build my project. The problem is that the script I need for the `EventSource` doesn't stop executing until it is done (in 30 seconds I get the time limit error, that's what it is "done"). When I reload the page, it doesn't stop loading until the 30 second limit error is triggered. Whatever page i'm on, I get this issue.

I didn't have this on my host so i'm wondering if there is some sort of setting in PHP that will allow me to disable this behavior.

My Script is:

```
    require "connect.php";
    require "user.php";

    date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");

    //ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);

    $wait = 1000;
    $curr = 0;
    $sM = "";
    while (1) {

        $number = $data["number"];
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `to`='$number' OR `from`='$number' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC) as mess GROUP BY `id`");
        $ql = $query->num_rows;

        if ($ql == 0) {
            echo 'data: null';
            echo "\n\n";
            exit();
        }

        if($curr != $ql){
            while ($rows = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                $to = $rows["to"];
                $id = $rows["id"];
                $choose = $to == $number ? $rows["from"] : $to;
                $side = $to == $number ? "To You:" : "From You:";
                $sM .= "<div class='messageBox sBox' onclick=\"Connect.messages.load($id, $to)\" data-id='$id'><name>$choose</name><div>$side " . $rows["message"] . "</div>";
                $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `messages` WHERE `to`='$number' OR `from`='$number' AND `status`='unread' AND `id`='$id'");
                if ($q->num_rows > 0) {
                    $sM .= "<span>" . $q->num_rows . "</span>";
                }   
                $sM .= "</div>";
            }
            echo 'data: '. $sM;
            echo "\n\n";
            $curr = $ql;
        }

        ob_flush();
        flush();
        usleep($wait * 1000);
    }
```

Basically this script runs until the time limit is reached (which I know I can change). But instead of stopping when you leave the script, it still runs in the background so pages don't load until its done. I originally had this project on the `WAMP` server. I figured it was the servers fault. But after also trying `XAMPP`, I figure there might be an option to change the behavior of this.

Comment: Just a guess but `$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `to`='$number' OR `from`='$number' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC) as mess GROUP BY `id`");` is your issue there's no table defined.  and the while(1) will mean  the script always runs until time out.

Comment: @Dave The query works fine because there is a table defined. And I know, but you aren't getting the issue. The issue is that I don't want it to run in the background. Meaning when you leave the script. It shouldn't even run on a different page.

Comment: Not seeing a table defined there its a `from(` which is incorrect anyway as its lacking the space.  As for it continuing to run even when you navigate away thats an oddity of php when you have a run away SQL issue. so if you do a mad sql query that takes say 10 minutes to run it'll lock the thread for your connection (your browser) until that query has completed regardless of if you navigate away or attempt to load a different page.  Set the query running in say FF then fire up chrome and navigate to your page it'll work fine but FF will be locked until your 30 seconds are up.  TLDR: fix sql